# Update two models in a given resource tastypie

Tags: django, tastypie

The problem statement is simple ,
2 Models : UserGames, UserHost

A post request is made by user to join a game then a record is created in UserGames, if Hosting parameter is passed in the request then UserGames and UserHost record is created.
UserHost has a foreign key reference to UserGames.

I am able to create UserGames record in **

- obj_create

** but i need the record UserGames object ID to create a record in UserHost.

**2nd Problem** , i need to **return in output an array UserGames** (`if user is not hosting`) or `else UserGames + UserHost combined array` .

Answer (score 4):

I tried implementing this using [abstract model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and then exposing that via `ModelResource`. I had to override `obj_create` and `get_resource_uri` method for this.

Please have a look at example code (I have tested this on my local machine).

### Models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserGame(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    # more fields like name etc.
    name = models.CharField("name", max_length=40)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class UserHost(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(UserGame)
    # more fields like hostname etc.
    hostname = models.CharField("host name", max_length=40)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hostname


class JoinGame(models.Model):
    game = models.ForeignKey(UserGame)
    host = models.ForeignKey(UserHost)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

### API Resource using Tastypie

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from tastypie import fields
from tastypie.authentication import (BasicAuthentication, ApiKeyAuthentication,
                                     MultiAuthentication)
from tastypie.authorization import Authorization
from tastypie.resources import Resource, ModelResource
from tastypie.exceptions import BadRequest

from .models import UserGame, UserHost, JoinGame


class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        resource_name = "user"
        # For authentication, allow both basic and api key so that the key
        # can be grabbed, if needed.
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(BasicAuthentication(),
                                             ApiKeyAuthentication())
        authorization = Authorization()

        # Because this can be updated nested under the other Resources.
        # It needs put/patch to be able to handle partial updates.
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'patch', 'put', ]
        always_return_data = True
        queryset = User.objects.all().select_related("api_key")
        excludes = ['is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'date_joined',
                    'last_login', 'password']


class UserGameResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user', full=True)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = "user_game"
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

        # Because this can be updated nested under the other Resources.
        # It needs put/patch to be able to handle partial updates.
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'put']
        always_return_data = True
        queryset = UserGame.objects.all()


class UserHostResource(ModelResource):
    resource_name = "user_host"
    user_game = fields.ForeignKey(UserGameResource, 'game', full=True)

    class Meta:
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

        # Because this can be updated nested under the other Resources.
        # It needs put/patch to be able to handle partial updates.
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post', 'patch', 'put']
        always_return_data = True
        queryset = UserHost.objects.all()
```

#### JoinGameResource

```
class JoinGameResource(Resource):
    game = fields.ForeignKey(UserGameResource, "game", null=True, full=True)
    host = fields.ForeignKey(UserHostResource, "host", null=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        resource_name = "join_game"
        object_class = JoinGame
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()
        authorization = Authorization()

        # Because this can be updated nested under the other Resources.
        # It needs put/patch to be able to handle partial updates.
        list_allowed_methods = ['post']
        detail_allowed_methods = []
        fields = ["game", "host"]
        always_return_data = True

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        if "game" not in bundle.data:
            raise BadRequest("Must provide 'game' when joining a game.")
        return bundle

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        try:
            game = bundle.data.get("game")
            game_bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=UserGame(), data=game,
                                            request=bundle.request)
            updated_game_bundle = UserGameResource().obj_create(
                game_bundle, **kwargs)
            bundle.obj.game = updated_game_bundle.obj
        except KeyError:
            raise BadRequest("Must provide 'game' when joining a game.")

        try:
            host = bundle.data.get("host")
            host_bundle = self.build_bundle(obj=UserHost(), data=host,
                                            request=bundle.request)
            updated_host_bundle = UserHostResource().obj_create(
                host_bundle, game=updated_game_bundle.obj, **kwargs)
            bundle.obj.host = updated_host_bundle.obj
        except KeyError:
            pass
            #raise BadRequest("Must provide 'host' when joining a host.")

        return bundle

    def get_resource_uri(self, updated_bundle):
        # Since JoinGame is abstract model, pk won't be available
        # So, get_resource_uri method of ModelResource will raise exception
        # Let's override that
        return None
```

### URLS

```
from .api import (
    UserResource, UserGameResource, UserHostResource, JoinGameResource)
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include
from tastypie.api import Api

# Create an empty pattern so that we can just build it using +=
urlpatterns = patterns(None)

#==============================================================================
# API Resources
#==============================================================================
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(UserResource())
v1_api.register(UserGameResource())
v1_api.register(UserHostResource())
v1_api.register(JoinGameResource())

urlpatterns += patterns(
    '',
    (r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
)
```

### Sample request body

```
{
    "game": {
        "name": "New Game",
        "user": "/api/v1/user/1/"
    },
    "host": {
        "hostname": "New Host name"
    }
}
```

### Sample response body

```
{
    "game": {
        "id": 15,
        "name": "New Game",
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/user_game/15/",
        "user": {
            "email": "psjinx@example.com",
            "first_name": "",
            "id": 1,
            "last_name": "",
            "resource_uri": "/api/v1/user/1/",
            "username": "psjinx"
        }
    },
    "host": {
        "hostname": "New Host name",
        "id": 13,
        "resource_uri": "/api/v1/userhost/13/",
        "user_game": {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "New Game",
            "resource_uri": "/api/v1/user_game/15/",
            "user": {
                "email": "psjinx@example.com",
                "first_name": "",
                "id": 1,
                "last_name": "",
                "resource_uri": "/api/v1/user/1/",
                "username": "psjinx"
            }
        }
    },
    "resource_uri": null
}
```

Comment: I tried creating using your sample answer : I recieve errors on obj_create method

Comment: class UserGamesHost(models.Model):
    UserGamesHostID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    UserGamesRealmID = models.ForeignKey(UserGamesRealm)
    RealmID = models.ForeignKey(Realms)

Comment: class UserGamesRealm(models.Model):
    UserGamesRealmID = UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    RealmID = models.ForeignKey(Realms)

Comment: I have been able to create an object for UserGamesRealm model and no issues in obtaining realm ID , the issue i am facing is creating an UserGameHost using userGameRealmID which is basically the id on USerGameRealm object i have just created.